# Changes To xaml don't reflect on App Until rebuild - windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-express

I have a weird problem in an windows phone 8 project (Visual Studio Express for windows phone 8) that Changes to xaml( ex:change visibility of control) don't reflect on App until I rebuild the project and deploy it again to emulator or device.

The changes reflect normally in the design window of visual studio but didn't reflect on the running App.

I did many researches and they didn't help, like:

1- Change "Build and Run" to "always build" when projects are out of date.

2- I checked configuration manager as [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049502/changes-are-not-happening-until-a-rebuild-is-performed) suggests but it was selected.

Comment: I would suggest deleting the contents of the `bin` and `obj` directories, then see if the problem is still there

Comment: @KooKiz I deleted bin and obj directories but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. still need to rebuild to see changes on the App.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue. I have a work around at the moment to save the hassle of rebuilding the solution because rebuilding deletes and re-installs the app and changes any saved settings you've made while debugging. The work around is to switch between configurations. So I'll execute the app in Debug, make some changes, then the next time I execute I change config to Release, and the changes are there.

The difference I can see is when it works I can see the Build Output line which says "Updating the application as the manifest file has changed..." take a few moments to complete. When this issue occurs the output line appears for a split second and so you can tell the incremental deployment hasn't actually been deployed to the device/emulator.

This is a little frustrating so hopefully someone has a real answer. I have other projects on the same machine and they don't have this issue. Just the one project so I don't think its a VS2012 problem.

I've also tried suggestions from other sites saying delete bin and obj folders but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had solved the problem a couple of weeks ago but I'm not sure which exact modification fixed the problem for me, but let me tell you one of the modifications i did to the project to solve this problem:

I noticed that when renaming or adding any control to xaml in some page, nothing will be reflected in code until i rebuild the app , 

The fix was to add "MSBuild:Compile" to the "CustomTool" property of  page.xaml (note it should be there by default!)

Comment: I have the same problem and can't understanad you solution @AhmedRashad , what do you mean by "MSBuildLCompile" , where I can add it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for some of my WP8 Silverlight projects in VS 2013. I couldn't understand why it happened only for some projects but not all, but eventually I found [this forum thread](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/winphone/wptools.aspx?ID=4c292e74-6be7-4585-8982-816d03740b55). The solution is the following: if the name of your app includes spaces, you definitely need to remove them or replace say with the underscore char. This recipe helped to recover my 'problem' projects.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that numbers at the beginning of app name cause the same problem. I solved it by removing numbers from solution and app name.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the question, but I see you can't comment. Please keep that in mind.